# Error: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, foreach

## What I want to do:

I want to filter through these arrays and see if there are any dates that are active at the same time.

### This is my Code:

```
loadAllAndCheckDates (recommendedSection: RecommendedSection): boolean {
        this.query()
            .subscribe((res: ResponseWrapper) => { this.fromDbRecommendedSections = res.json; }, (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onError(res.json));

        return this.checkDates(recommendedSection);
    }

    checkDates (currentRecSec: RecommendedSection): boolean {

        this.fromDbRecommendedSections.forEach((recSecDB:RecommendedSection) =>{
            var dbActiveFrom = new Date(recSecDB.activeFrom);
            var dbActiveTo = new Date(recSecDB.activeTo);
            var currActiveFrom = new Date(currentRecSec.activeFrom);
            var currActiveTo = new Date(currentRecSec.activeTo);
             if(dbActiveFrom.getTime() === currActiveFrom.getTime()){
                this.isDouble = true;
             }if (dbActiveTo.getTime() === currActiveTo.getTime()){
                this.isDouble = true;
             }if(dbActiveFrom > currActiveFrom && dbActiveFrom < currActiveTo){
                 this.isDouble = true;
             }if(dbActiveTo > currActiveFrom && dbActiveTo < currActiveTo){
                 this.isDouble = true;
             }
        }, (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onError(res.json));
        return this.isDouble;
    }
```

### The Problem:

Sadly I get the following Error in the console: *Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined*

### Edit:

Here is how fromDbRecommendedSection is set up:

```
export class RecommendedSection implements BaseEntity {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public activeFrom?: any,
        public activeTo?: any,
        public identification?: string,
        public recommendedSectionNames?: RecommendedSectionName,
        public recommendedSectionItems?: RecommendedSectionItem[],
    ) {
        this.recommendedSectionItems = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the value of this.fromDbRecommendedSections

Comment: after fex edits this I hope my answer will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should process data synchronously in your example the delay of getting a response might be too high before you get `this.fromDbRecommendedSections` populated. So by the time you return `this.checkDates` `this.fromDbRecommendedSections` is `undefined`.

try

```
loadAllAndCheckDates (recommendedSection: RecommendedSection): boolean {
        this.query()
            .subscribe((res: ResponseWrapper) => {
                this.fromDbRecommendedSections = res.json; // needs to be an array
                this.checkDates(recommendedSection)
            }, (error:any) => console.log(error);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the case.

Comment: @matsch happy to help